# Two arguments to closure function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a email send function:

```
   Mail::send('emails.message', ['text'=> $email['message']], function($message, $email)
    {
        $message->to($email['email'], 'Name')->subject('Subj'); 
    });
```

And now i have a error:
`Missing argument 2 for {closure}()`
How i can flash `$email` to the my closure function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ($message) use ($email) {
   //...
}
```